# Copying/pasting a column of formulas using python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a very large excel file that I'm dealing with in python. I have a column where every cell is a different formula. I want to copy the formulas and paste them one column over from column GD to GE.

The issue is that I want to the formulas to update like they do in excel, its just that excel takes a very long time to copy/paste because the file I'm working with is very large.

Any ideas on possibly how to use openpyxl's translator to do this or anything else?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
#loads the excel file and is now saved under workbook#
workbook = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
#uses the individual sheets index(first sheet = 0) to work on one sheet at a time#
sheet= workbook.worksheets[8]
#inserts a column at specified index number#
sheet.insert_cols(187)
#naming the new columns#
sheet['GE2']= '20220531'
```

here is my updated code

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.formula.translate import Translator
#loads the excel file and is now saved under workbook#
workbook = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
#uses the individual sheets index(first sheet = 0) to work on one sheet at a time#
sheet= workbook.worksheets[8]
formula = sheet['GD3'].value
new_formula = Translator(formula, origin= 'GE3').translate_formula("GD3")
sheet['GD2'] = new_formula
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=187, max_col=188):
    old, new = row
    if new.data_type != "f":
        continue
    new_formula = Translator(new.value, origin=old.coordinate).translate_formula(new.coordinate)
workbook.save('file.xlsx')
```

Comment: Have you tried inserting a column in Excel instead of copy/pasting?

Comment: Openpyxl won't calculate the formulas for you tho.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I have already inserted the new column. I then want to copy formulas and paste them all in the new column

Comment: I added a bit of my code where I added the new column GE. I wanted to copy the formulas in GD to GE and have them update like they would in excel. Some of the files have 60000+ rows so that's why I'd like to do this process in python

Comment: If you insert a column _in Excel to the left of the formulas_ it will shift the formulas to the right by one column, effectively moving them from GD to GE.

Comment: Inserting a column at GD with Openpyxl will mean that GE then has the formulas that GD had (GD is then an empty column). However as Big Ben says, be aware that Openpyxl does not manage formulas when inserting/deleting rows/cols. Therefore if there are columns after GE they will still reference the same cell as before the insert, e.g if there was a formula in cell GF1 that referenced GD1, after the insert GF1 formula is now in GG1 but unlike when doing insert column in Excel the formula will still reference GD1 rather than GE1. Xlwings will update the formulas when inserting/deleting rows/cols.

Answer (score 1):

When you add or remove columns and rows, Openpyxl does not manage formulae for you. The reason for this is simple: where should it stop? Managing a "dependency graph" is exactly the kind of functionality that an application like MS Excel provides.

But it is quite easy to do this in your own code using the [Formula Translator](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formula.html#translating-formulae-from-one-location-to-another)

```py
# insert the column
formula = ws['GE1'].value
new_formula = Translator(formula, origin="GD1").translate_formula("GE1")
ws['GE1'] = new_formula
```

It should be fairly straightforward to create a loop for this (check the data type and use `cell.coordinate` to avoid potential typos or incorrect adjustments.

```py
sheet.insert_cols(187)
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=187, max_col=188):
    old, new = row
    if new.data_type != "f"
        continue
    new_formula = Translator(new.value, origin=old.coordinate).translate_formula(new.coordinate)
```

Comment: I got an error message at the line old, new = row. It said too many values to unpack

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong parameters on iter_rows(). `min_col` and `max_col` are what you need. You should get used to this method.

Comment: I posted my updated code. The formulas start in row 3, which is why I have GD3 and GE3. Will this go through every row in each column? There is about 60,000 rows that have to be copied from GD to GE

Comment: It will unless you tell it not to. As I said, read up on the method.